# Text in div element is raised above horizontally aligned span element in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a web application, where support tickets are shown with the ticket ID on the left as static text, and the remaining fields (description, severity, duration, status, reporter) are shown on the right as scrolling text in a fixed size viewport.

I started with a `<span>` containing the ticket ID, and a viewport `<div>` containing a second `<span>` with the remaining fields, and an animated `left` property (represented by `#attempt1` in the example).  This works fine in Chrome and Safari, but the scrolling text is raised above the static text in Firefox (I can't use Internet Explorer, because it doesn't support web sockets; I haven't tried Opera yet).

I tried replacing the viewport `<div>` with another `<span>` (represented by `#attempt2`) but then the text is overlapped, because the `overflow:hidden` style is ignored.  Just to see what happened, I also added the `display:inline-block` style to the replacement `<span>` (represented by `#attempt3`) and it behaves like the original `<div>`.

I've created a cut-down example showing this behaviour, where the scrolling text elements have a hard-coded `left` property; please see this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uLAm6/.

[image: First attempt, with scrolling text raised above static text]

[image: Second attempt, with scrolling text overlapping static text]

Can anyone (i) explain why Firefox is showing the raised text, and (ii) suggest a way to make any of the attempts in my example work like they do in Chrome?  Many thanks!

Comment: remove .animated left:-48px; in your div

Comment: I got a catch here. Refer to the bug- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=491549

Comment: Thanks, but removing the `left` property sort of defeats the purpose; I want to scroll that text by animating its `left` property!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every browser render differently that why we [RESET](http://html5boilerplate.com/) this. In your case there 2 or 3 factors which effect elements misalignment. **SPAN** is an `inline` element so there default align is `baseline` for this define vertical-align:top. Write like this:

```
.static,.viewport
{
    vertical-align:top;
}
body{
    line-height:1;
}
```

Check this for more http://jsfiddle.net/uLAm6/6/

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain (i), but for (ii), specify

```
vertical-align: bottom
```

for the second span.

By the way, you can use

```
<div>
```

for both areas, and hard-code the width of the ticket ID, if you want to avoid vertical alignment peculiarities.

Answer (score 0):

I could now answer this question as I have been through this situation enough. There is a problem in firefox(maybe you can call it a bug) with `"overflow:hidden;"` attribute. you see, if you remove `"overflow:hidden"` attribute from you `"viewport"` class in CSS, you get the same styling as in chrome.

The problem is listed as in [here](http://www.impressivewebs.com/overflow-hidden-problem/)

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately I need the `overflow:hidden;` to stop the animated text showing outside the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

[See Working DEMO](http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp8g)
For first option you we can't give div as display inline block. Because it will be inline with div element only.

HTML

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id='attempt1'>
      <span class='static'>
        This text is static
      </span>
      <div class='viewport'>
        <span class='animated'>
          This text is raised in Firefox
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id='attempt2'>
      <span class='static'>
        This text is static
      </span>
      <span class='viewport'>
        <span class='animated'>
          This text is overlapped in Firefox and Chrome
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div id='attempt3'>
      <span class='static'>
        This text is static
      </span>
      <span class='viewport'>
        <span class='animated'>
          This text is raised in Firefox
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.static
{
  background-color:#ffc0c0;
}

.viewport
{
  background-color:#c0ffc0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.animated
{
  position:relative;

}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, if you put the `left:-48px;` back in, you still get overlapped text.  However, the `vertical-align` solutions suggested by a couple of people fix the problem.